# Правильно ли я объяснил постановку знаков препинания и расставил их?(3)

Tags: пунктуация

*Но вдруг, (перед обстоятельство, выраженным деепричастным оборотом) поднимаясь из небольшого оврага, при выезде из гор, на крутом повороте, (запятые между уточняющими обстоятельствами места, последняя запятая закрывает деепричастный оборот) он грянул о землю. Печорин проворно соскочил, (между однородными сказуемыми) хотел поднять его - напрасно (тире ставится, когда вторая часть - она здесь неполная - выражает противопоставление, содержащееся в первой части, можно поставить союз "но"); едва слышный стон вырвался сквозь стиснутые его зубы; через несколько минут он издох. (Точка с запятой разделяет простые предложения в составе БСП).*

Проверьте, пожалуйста, объяснение поставленных знаков препинания

Comment: Судя по последнему "вопросику", вы или вовсе не удосужились подумать или не владеете даже азами школьной программы.  Постарайтесь найти хоть какое-то правило на эти знаки.

Comment: @behemothus думаю что в последнем запятая перед БСП

Comment: @behemothus переделал,проверьте пожалуйста