# Правильно ли я объяснил постановку знаков препинания и расставил их?

Tags: пунктуация

И между тем он все скакал, (запятая перед деепричастным оборотом) погоняя беспощадно. (логически просится новое предложение) Вдруг Печорин стал замечать, (запятая перед придаточным изъяснительным в СПП) что его конь дышит все тяжелее. (Снова другое предложение) Истощенный безумной скачкой, (причастный оборот обособляется, так как определяемое слово - личное местоимение) он раза два уже споткнулся на ровном месте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*И между тем он все скакал, погоняя беспощадно. Вдруг Печорин стал замечать, что его конь дышит все тяжелее. **Истощенный безумной скачкой**, он раза два уже споткнулся на ровном месте.*

Вы всё верно объяснили. Можно только еще добавить, что причастный оборот имеет дополнительное обстоятельственное значение (причины).

Сравнить: ***Истощенный безумной скачкой**, конь раза два уже споткнулся на ровном месте.* Здесь нет личного местоимения, но оборот все равно обособляется.

Comment: в вашем примере обособляется так как причастный оборот имеет дополнительное обстоятельственное значение (причины);?

Comment: Да, именно так. А в приведенном тексте основной причиной является то, что  причастный оборот не образует словосочетания с местоимением.

Comment: понял, [сслыка на похожее задание, проверьте пожалуйста](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462719/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d1%853)

Comment: ам все верно. Кстати, вы неплохо знаете грамматику и правильно объясняете постановку знаков препинания. Что можно добавить? Точка с запятой ставится в БСП, если предложения достаточно самостоятельны по смыслу. Запятые здесь меньше подойдут, так как события не следуют сразу одно за другим.