# Правильно ли я объяснил постановку знаков препинания и расставил их? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

Оставалось всего пять верст до той станицы, (запятая перед придаточным определительным в СПП) где он мог пересесть на другую лошадь, свежую и бодрую (запятая между однородными определениями). (Далее новое предложение -  логически подходит только так). Все было бы спасено, (запятая перед придаточным условия) если бы у коня, (запятая перед причастным оборотом) несущегося из последних сил, (конец причастного оборота) достало сил еще на десять минут.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильно ли я объяснил постановку знаков препинания и расставил их?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462721/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d1%85)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Оставалось всего пять верст до той станицы, где он мог пересесть на **другую** лошадь, **свежую и бодрую.** Все было бы спасено, если бы у коня, несущегося из последних сил, достало сил еще на десять минут.*

Обособление определения «свежую и бодрую»  в позиции после определяемого слова «лошадь» связано с его **пояснительным характером** относительно местоимения «другую» в препозиции.

Все остальное объясняется верно.

Comment: спасибо, а что значит в препозиции?

Comment: Препозиция - это позиция определения "другую" перед определяемым словом.